# Calculating the Sum of a List of Numbers

Tags: algorithm, list

I try to grasp the concept of lists, this is new for me: I only solve algorithms by using Arrays.
So in order to calculate the sum of a list of numbers, what does this code really do?

Pseudo-code:

```
function listSum(intList:List):Integer
if isEmpty(rest(intList)) then
                listSum:=first(intList)
           else
                listSum:=first(intList) + listSum(rest(intList)) 
print(listsum([1,3,5,7,9]))
```

I read [this explanation](http://interactivepython.org/runestone/static/pythonds/Recursion/pythondsCalculatingtheSumofaListofNumbers.html#lst-recsum) but I still don't understand how it proceed.

Could you make me understand it, please?

Comment: Is this a python programming question?

Comment: Not exactly, I'm studying an algorithm course in java.

Answer (score 1):

Its best to try to explain line-by-line whats going on:

```
function listSum(intList:List):Integer
    if isEmpty(intList)
        then listSum:=first(intList)
    else
        listSum:=first(intList) + listSum(rest(intList))

print(listsum([1,3,5,7,9]))
```

This code is recursively passing the array to find the result.

For example, lets say you have the following array:

```
[1,2,3,5]
```

When you pass the array into the function, it will check to see if the array isEmpty.

It isn't so it goes to the else block.

The else block says "return the first item in this list, plus the rest of the list". The "rest of the list" is obtained by passing the remainder of the array the listSum function.

More concisely the function results would look like:

```
[1,2,3,5]
1 + [2,3,5]
1 + 2 + [3,5]
1 + 2 + 3 + [5]
1 + 2 + 3 + 5
1 + 2 + 8
1 + 10
11
```

Key takeaway is the pseudocode is solving the problem recursively.

[More info on recursion here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursion)

Comment: The first element is 1 and the rest is [2,3,5], so how does the next recursion 1 + 2 + [3,5] work?

Comment: So each additional iteration is called with `listSum(rest(intList))`. You're talking in pseudo-code, but the assumption is that `rest` returns all elements except the first. That said, the following snippet: `if isEmpty(intList)        then listSum:=first(intList)` seems wrong.

Comment: @TheIronDevelopper    `if isEmpty(rest(intList))`     then, you're right I omitted the rest(List) which executes when the final case is met: i.e when the rest of the list is empty. So, if the list is empty it adds an undefined element to the sum?

Comment: Or if its empty it will add 0... but yea, you got the right idea.  Personally speaking, recursion doesn't make too much sense for this use-case.... but you were asking for help on this particular implementation.